# UIWebView displays image differently on iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: html, ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

**Basic Scenario**:

I have an image that is 2048x1536.
I have an html file that displays this image via CSS that specifies a width of 1024 and height of 768.
I have an UIWebView that displays that html page.

**Problem**:

On an iOS6 device, that image is resized to fit within that 1024x768 area.  On an iOS7 device, that image is cropped to only display the top left quarter of the image.

Since iOS7, Chrome, and Safari all do the cropping option, I do believe that is the correct behavior (I strongly suspect that the latest webkit was updated to match this standard behavior).  However, for business reasons, I still need the resize behavior.

**Question**:

Is it possible to still to keep that resize behavior even on iOS7?

**EDIT** - Additional info based on comments:

I presented a highly simplified scenario.  I can't just put the image into an image view.  The feature within my app allows 3rd parties to load their HTML content into it.  Also, related to that, I can NOT modify the HTML contents.  Basically, all I can do is create a NSUrlRequest for that HTML content and tell the UIWebView to load it via loadRequest.

Below are the HTML snippet and CSS snippet.  But please keep in mind that I can't change this.  I only control the objective-c end of things.

```
    <body >
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
    </body>



#wrapper {
background-color: #FFF;
position: relative;
width: 1024px;
height: 768px;
background: #FFF url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat top left;
background-size: contain;
overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: Why do you do this when you could just use a UIImageView with content mode Aspect Fit?

Comment: have you set a viewport meta tag specifying width/height and scale?

Comment: screenshots pls... it will help us a lot...

Comment: Code would help more than a screenshot. What CSS are you using to size the image?